# Return promise on an event

Tags: javascript

**Problem Statement**

I want to upload some images when user drops on dropZone. What i am doing is upload them to server and then return promise to do further actions like hiding the dropZone,  display success message and move user to the next step.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
      /* ajax call */
      resolve(value);
    });
  });
```

The issue i am facing is if a user drops the files two times then drop event is triggering twice and promise is trying to resolve a already resolved promise.

I want to return every time a new promise on the occurrence of event.

Comment: you can't use promises for this, since a promise can only be resolved once - refactor your code that wants to listen for such events to **listen** for such events

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you know the total number of files? Promises don't work like this. Promise can be used to know when all files are done though

Comment: You can basically disable the dropzone when you are processing the first file by setting state and toggle back the state when the promise is resolved

Comment: I want to return a new Promise every time a event triggers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve promise into addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613894/resolve-promise-into-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2):

Return promise inside the event like

```
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     /* ajax call */
     resolve(value);
   });
});
```

Comment: Exactly right: 1) Add an event listener, 2) ONLY when the event actually FIRES 3) create the Promise :)

Comment: how do you get the promise though? are the return values of such callback handlers accessible?

Comment: You have to make your promise, that's why wrote return new promise....

Comment: I don't think you understood my point.
How can you possibly access the returned promises at top level (outside the callback)?
It doesn't make sense to return such values inside a callback (except few cases like `.map()`, etc..) because these returned values just become inaccessible elsewhere. (specially inside event-handling callbacks)

Comment: Usually returns inside event-handlers are used to indicate if the events have been cancelled, not for custom value returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling promise inside a function, Make sure you're not invoking the function frequently, As I see, drop `event` is created repeatedly in the promise if you invoke promise multiple times. If you want call function many times, remove the event listener and add it again.

you can simply use async/await for ajax call.

```
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', async function(event) {
    try {
       const response = await doFileUploadHere()
       return response;
    } catch(err) {
       console.log('error while uploading the files', err)
    }
  });
```