# Why does my button need to be pressed twice to restart a loop with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

The program runs a loop continuously until I press a button that pauses the loop. When I press the button a second time it should start running continuously. What happens now is on the first press it stops. Then the second press runs the loop once and stops again. When I press a third time, however, it does start running continuously again. How do I fix this?

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function program_loop() {
    for (word_iterator = 0; word_iterator < some_length; word_iterator++) {
        if (stop == true) await pauser();
        //mini example
        word.innerHTML = text_words[word_iterator]
        await timer(200); 
    }
}
```

```
function pauser() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let playbuttonclick = function () {
            if (stop == false) {
                stop = true;
                pausebutton.innerHTML = 'Start'
            }
            else if (stop == true) {
                stop = false;
                pausebutton.innerHTML = 'Stop'  
            }  
        resolve('resolved')
        }
    pausebutton.addEventListener('click', playbuttonclick)
    })
}
```

I've tried removing the `if (stop==true) await pauser()` but this ruins my whole program. Since then I need to press the button to advance the loop.

Comment: Replace `if (stop == true)` to `while (stop)`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45858738/4543207) about resolving promises in eventlisteners.

Comment: while(stop) gives the same result except that the loop now doesn't run once anymore on the second button press

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call pauser() , you add a new button click handler. Therefore, after several cycles, several handlers are triggered at once. Install the handler once or remove the old one each time.

Try this example:

```
const pausebutton = document.getElementById('pauseButton');
let stop = false;
const some_length = 500;
let promiseResolve;

const handleToggleStop = () => {
  stop = !stop;
  promiseResolve && promiseResolve();
};

pausebutton.addEventListener('click', handleToggleStop);

const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function program_loop() {
    for (word_iterator = 0; word_iterator < some_length; word_iterator++) {
        if (stop) {
          await new Promise((resolve) => {
            promiseResolve = resolve;
          });
        }
        //mini example
        await timer(1000); 
    }
}

program_loop();
```

Comment: I have already tried using .removeEventListener and then calling .addEventListener again but it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `pauser` function. You can do as follows;

```js
let timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)),
    word  = document.getElementById("word"),
    bttn  = document.getElementById("pause-button"),
    prms  = Promise.resolve(),
    rslv;

async function program_loop() {
    for (let word_iterator = 0; word_iterator < 1e6; word_iterator++) {
        await prms;
        word.innerText = word_iterator;
        await timer(200); 
    }
}

bttn.addEventListener("click", _e => {
    if (rslv) {
        rslv();
        rslv = null;
        bttn.innerText = "STOP";
    } else {
        prms = new Promise(v => rslv = v);
        bttn.innerText = "START";
    }
});

program_loop();
```

```html
<button id="pause-button">STOP</button>
<div id="word"></div>
```